# Cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to 'char[]'

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
char[] chname1=new char[20];
char[] chname2=new char[20];
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void btsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chname1 = Convert.ToChar(txtname1.Text);
    chname2 = Convert.ToChar(txtname2.Text);
    Response.Write(chname1.ToString().Length+"---"+chname2.ToString().Length);
}
}
```

This is a simple asp.net code,i cannot convert char to char array...
How to find the character at ch[i] th position?

Comment: what are you trying to do anyway? if you only need to print out string size why to cast to char then to do toString again !?!?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got a string, and you're trying to convert it to `char`, and then assign the result to a `char[]` variable.

Are you sure you don't just want:

```
chname1 = txtname1.Text.ToCharArray();
```

Note that calling `ToString()` on a `char[]` probably doesn't do what you want it to either... converting a `char[]` to a `string` is normally done via `new string(char[])`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ToCharArray()` method of the `string` class:

```
chname1 = txtname1.Text.ToCharArray();
```

But what are you trying to do exactly? if you only need the length, there is no need to convert to char[], just use

```
txtname1.Text.Length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use txtname1.Text.SubString(startPosition-1, 1)

Comment: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'SubString' and no extension method 'SubString' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: it is Substring -> no capital S in string

Answer (score 1):

To convert a `string` to `char` array:

```
chname1 = txtname1.Text.ToCharArray()
```

[*(ToCharArray documentation)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`txtname1.Text[i]` should actually work I guess...

Comment: my problem is ,i need to convert char to char[].It is not possile

Answer (score 0):

What is it you are trying to achieve? Are your txtname1 and textname2 textboxes? In that case why bother with an array of chars. Just use strings and substring functionality.